# Validation of formula like we enter in excel

Tags: javascript, regex, excel-formula

I'm working on jquery.sheet to make data grid and spreadsheet I'm facing challenge on validating a formula in a specific cell.

What i want to achieve is that when i left cell (on focusout event) a validator runs and check if that is valid formula input or not.

i tried to do it by building a regex but was not able to cover all valid cases as they are in excel.

Every excel like formula are valid

is there any js library or regex to do so ?

some examples:
 Formula start with "="

> =A1+B1 (Valid)
>   =$A1 (Valid)
>   =A$1 (Valid)
>   =A$1 + B1 (Valid)
>   =A1 (Valid)
>   =A1 + (InValid)
>   =11 + A1 (Valid)
>   = 11 + (InValid)
>   = SUM(A1,A2)
>   = SUM(A1+A2)

All formulas that are present in excel are should get validate

All four arithmetic operations are valid too.

Comment: You can't do that with regex. Write your own parser.

Answer (score 0):

This satisfies your test data:

```
^=([A-Z0-9$]+)([ +*\/-]+[A-Z0-9$]+)*$
```

See [demo on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/3H7xun/2)

UPD: If you want to validate 100% of Excel formulas and not a limited subset, then it's impossible to do via regex. Don't parse Excel formulas with regex. Regex is just not the right tool to parse Excel formulas. Here's an example of a valid formula taken from [Redis](https://www.reddit.com/r/excel/comments/8ynevq/longest_excel_formula_ive_had_to_create_so_far/):

[image]

Comment: Well it doesn't as i have also added few more examples to clear the confusion out.
it should verify all types of formula we have in excel

Comment: well now that you've changed your question it doesn't fit any more :) Do you want all excel functions or just SUM?

Comment: well my bad i have made my question more clear now.
all sort of excel functions,formulas moreover any sort of formula we use in excel we just validate that it's correct or not ? 
basically I'm using jquery.sheet in that i want to validate formula like excel

Comment: In this case I don't think you can use a regex. Excel formulas can be very complicated, i.e. `SUM(SUM(IF($A1, B4, B0), A1:A223))`

Comment: thta's why i said regex or any library to do this